# Removing country domain name using mod_rewrite

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have bought both an international domain (.com) and a Brazilian domain (.com.br). I need to redirect people from the Brazilian domain to the international one, so that thewebsite.com.br/contact goes to thewebsite.com/contact. On top of that, I would also like to remove the www both from the Brazilian and international domain names. So that www.thewebsite.com.br/contact takes my user to thewebsite.com/contact.

I am using the Drupal .htaccess rewrite rule for removing the www:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

What do you recommend? Adapt this rule to remove the international .br or add another rule on top of this to remove the .br? How would be the final mod_rewrite condition for both removing www and .br from my URLs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Enable rewrite
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Rewrite .br to international domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com.br [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
# Rewrite non www. .br to international domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com.br [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
# Rewrite www. to non www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you. The only  problem is that this code won't redirect domain.com.br to domain.com because it does not search for domain.com.br without .www. I could add a third rule to take care of the .com.br without the .www. Or is this a bad practice? Is there a way to solve all this with one rule?

Comment: Sorry you're right, I've edited the original to include the non www .br to. It's fine to use multiple rules to achieve it.

Comment: If you need every ounce of performance you should move any htaccess rules to httpd.conf and disable htaccess files which will give you a boost for every page load.