# mod_rewrite to remove last part of domain name while keeping the rest of the URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using apache2 and mod_rewrite as a proxy server for a development environment.  I need to be able to rewrite an incoming request where I remove the last part of the host's domain name.

Example:

Original -request: https://rc.example.com.dev.example.com/some/url

Rewritten request: https://rc.example.com/some/url

If someone sends a request for rc.example.com.dev.example.com I need to be able to strip off the ".dev.example.com" part and rewrite the HTTP_HOST part to be https://rc.example.com/some/url

I've found lots of articles on how to remove the www from the beginning of the host name and how to remove the country abbreviation from the end of the host name.  However in the examples I have found, the solutions are hard coding the domain name in the rewritten host name.  I don't know what the host name is going to be so I can't hard code it.  I only know what I want removed from the end of the host name and it's ".dev.example.com"

I'm sure there is a way to use variables to capture the host name and remove the ".dev.example.com" part but I have not found an example for this.

Comment: What effect do you want this to have? Do you need the edited host name to be visible to an application, e.g. in an environment variable? Or do you need other Apache configuration to be loaded based on it? Or do you want to redirect the user's browser to request the new URL? Also, can you show some of the examples you found that looked close but not quite what you wanted?

Comment: I want the apache server to forward the original request on to the target server at rc.example.com (or whatever the domain is) and hand the reply back to the original requester.  The apache server is acting as a proxy.  The apache proxy looks at the host name in the incoming request and strips off the proxy part of the host name then forwards the request on the the target host.  My proxy is host is dev.example.com and if the incoming request is for some-other-internal-domain.com.dev.example.com then mod_rewrite rewrites it to https://some-other-internal-domain.com/some/url   Getting links now.

Comment: Now I can't find the stackoverflow post where the guy was wanting to remove the .br country code from http_host.  That post was the one that showed how to remove the .br part but leave the rest but the rest of it was hard coded.  OK I found it again:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970945/removing-country-domain-name-using-mod-rewrite

Comment: Here is the post that shows how to remove the www at beginning of the http_host but that is also hard coded:     https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/apache-web-server/adding-or-removing-the-www-prefix-in-domain-urls

Answer (score 0):

This post held the answer for me:

[apache mod_rewrite rule parse or split subdomain to find virtual host entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285762/apache-mod-rewrite-rule-parse-or-split-subdomain-to-find-virtual-host-entry)

I was able to cobble this together:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)+[\.]dev[\.]example[\.]com [NC]

RewriteRule (.*)$ https://%1$1 [P]
```

I tested this and it works.  Now I just need to figure out how to determine if the original request was http or https and make sure I keep the rewritten request the same.  But that's another issue.  This one is solved.